# Fatal error: putty Cannot connect to my ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, putty

It's my first time on aws and i want to upload a python script on ec2. Everything goes smoothly but when i try to connect to the server using putty, i get the following error:
[image]

I have no idea how to proceed. I am using linux mint 18 and one of the ubuntu instances in ec2
Any ideas? The associated questions aren't helping.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the command line SSH client on Linux machines, PuTTY expects you to enter only the hostname, here just `ec2-18-188-53-9.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com`, in the field "Host Name (or IP address)".

You'll need to enter the user `ubuntu` in the "Auto-login username" field under Connection -> Data, or leave it blank and enter it when you connect.  You'll also likely need to provide the location of your private key under Connection -> SSH -> Auth.